# Making a responsive interactive background image

Tags: jquery, html, css, background, responsive

I am making a website for someone and I am not sure on how to achieve what they are asking for.

Basically they want a responsive full screen page with an image similar to this as the background.

[image: Background example]

They then want me to fill the frames with images of people from the company, and to make it so a coloured overlay appears over the images when rolled over. I would then make modals appear when they are clicked similar to this [website](http://blue-apple.co.uk/people/).

I have looked into image maps and jQuery plug ins to make them responsive but they don't seem to be as accurate as I would like. Basically I can't get the maps to stay exactly over the pictures when changing the screen size.

Comment: please share your code.

Comment: .imageMap a {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background:#000;
    z-index:100;
    opacity:0.2;
    filter: alpha(opacity=20);
    border:1px solid transparent;
    border-radius:10px;
}

.imageMap a.p1 {
    left:25%;
    top:5%;
    width: 15%;
    height:30%;
}

Comment: I would be able to get it to appear ontop of a frame, but when I resize the window, it moves out of synch.

Comment: i want full code in jsfiddle or stackoverflow snippet..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adamhails/w9vss32m/

Comment: it's look so difficult..you want to some people pics in that frames and this people pics always stays in frames when resizing window in any resolution. m i right?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much.